# Unmanaged Threads Spring Quartz Websphere Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, websphere, quartz-scheduler

It appears that our implementation of using Quartz - JDBCJobStore along with Spring, Hibernate and Websphere is throwing unmanaged threads.

I have done some reading and found a tech article from IBM stating that the usage of Quartz with Spring will cause that.  They make the suggestion of using CommnonJ to address this issue.

I have done some further research and the only examples I have seen so far all deal with the plan old JobStore that is not in a database.

So, I was wondering if anyone has an example of the solution for this issue.

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "throwing unmanaged threads"?

Comment: It was reported to me by our WAS team, that when our application is running there are threads that are spawned, in a unmanged state - that is not attached to anything, GC can not get to them.  Based on reading from the IBM website, this can happen when using Quartz.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

We have a working solution for this (two actually).

1) Alter the quartz source code to use a WorkManager daemon thread for the main scheduler thread.  It works, but requires changing quarts.  We didn't use this though since we didn't want maintain a hacked version of quartz.  (That reminds me, I was going to submit this to the project but completely forgot)

2) Create a WorkManagerThreadPool to be used as the quartz threadpool.  Implement the interface for the quartz ThreadPool, so that each task that is triggered within quartz is wrapped in a commonj Work object that will then be scheduled in the WorkManager.  The key is that the WorkManager in the WorkManagerThreadPool has to be initialized before the scheduler is started, from a Java EE thread (such as servlet initialization).  The WorkManagerThreadPool must then create a daemon thread which will handle all the scheduled tasks by creating and scheduling the new Work objects.  This way, the scheduler (on its own thread) is passing the tasks to a managed thread (the Work daemon).

Not simple, and unfortunately I do not have code readily available to include.

Comment: I realize this post is old but do you have an example of how you were able to either change Quartz to use a WorkManager daemon thread, or creating a WorkManagerThreadPool that can be used as the Quartz threadpool? I would like to use Quartz with Websphere but realize the limitations of unmanaged threads, and want to do it the "right way". Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

Adding another answer to the thread, since i found a solution for this, finally.

**My environment**: WAS 8.5.5, Quartz 1.8.5, no Spring.

**The problem** i had was the (above stated) unmanaged thread causing a NamingException from `ctx.lookup(myJndiUrl)`, that was instead correctly working in other application servers (JBoss, Weblogic); actually, Webpshere was firing an "incident" with the following message:

> *javax.naming.ConfigurationException: A JNDI operation on a "java:" name cannot be completed because the server runtime is not able to associate the operation's thread with any J2EE application component. This condition can occur when the JNDI client using the "java:" name is not executed on the thread of a server application request. Make sure that a J2EE application does not execute JNDI operations on "java:" names within static code blocks or in threads created by that J2EE application. Such code does not necessarily run on the thread of a server application request and therefore is not supported by JNDI operations on "java:" names.*

The following steps solved the problem:

**1)**  upgraded to quartz 1.8.6 (no code changes), just maven pom

**2)**  added the following dep to classpath (in my case, EAR's /lib folder), to make the new WorkManagerThreadExecutor available

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.quartz-scheduler</groupId>
  <artifactId>quartz-commonj</artifactId>
  <version>1.8.6</version>
</dependency>
```

Note: in [QTZ-113](http://jira.terracotta.org/jira/browse/QTZ-113) or the official Quartz Documentation [1.x](http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-1.x/configuration/) [2.x](http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.2.x/configuration/) there's no mention on how to activate this fix.

**3)**  added the following to quartz.properties ("wm/default" was the JNDI of the already configured DefaultWorkManager in my WAS 8.5.5, see *Resources -> AsynchronousBeans -> WorkManagers* in WAS console):

```
org.quartz.threadExecutor.class=org.quartz.custom.WorkManagerThreadExecutor
org.quartz.threadExecutor.workManagerName=wm/default
```

Note: right class is *org.quartz.**custom**.WorkManagerThreadExecutor* for quartz-scheduler-1.8.6 (tested), or *org.quartz.**commonj**.WorkManagerThreadExecutor* from **2.1.1** on (not tested, but verified within actual [quartz-commonj's jars](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.quartz-scheduler/quartz-commonj) on maven's repos)

**4)**  moved the **JNDI lookup in the empty constructor of the quartz job** (thanks to [m_klovre's "Thread outside of the J2EE container"](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?61458-Spring-Quartz-JNDI-in-WebSphere-problem&p=233179#post233179)); that is, the constructor was being invoked by reflection (`newInstance()` method) from the very same J2EE context of my application, and had access to `java:global` namespace, while the `execute(JobExecutionContext)` method was still running in a poorer context, which was missing all of my application's EJBs

Hope this helps.

Ps. as a reference, you can find [here](https://gist.github.com/pcompieta/783eeea8341e532ba9f7) an example of the quartz.properties file I was using above

Comment: I know have been years, but is there a chance you can find and share the full content of quartz.properties file?

Comment: Sure, here it is - hope that helps. Also, please upvote my answer if you find it useful.

Comment: Thank you! But I keep struggling with the problem. The difference I've got in my environment is Quartz 2.2. Not sure what else should I try, if I get any advance will let you know.

Comment: I would like to read m_klovre's "Thread outside of the J2EE container" as mentioned in answer; but those forums are terminated on spring.io. Where else can I find those details ? Please comment.

Answer (score 3):

Check this article:
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/techjournal/0609_alcott/0609_alcott.html

basically, set the taskExecutor property on SchedulerFactoryBean to use a org.springframework.scheduling.commonj.WorkManager TaskExecutor which will use container managed threads.

Comment: This solution took us 2 minutes to implement (you can reuse the default wm jndi from WAS) and works perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

Just a note: the above QUARTZ-708's link is not valid anymore.
This new issue (in a new Jira) *seems* to be addressing the problem: http://jira.terracotta.org/jira/browse/QTZ-113 (fixVersion = 1.8.6, 2.0.2)

Answer (score 2):

I have recently encountered this problem. Practically you need:

1. Implement thread pool by delegating work to Websphere Work Manager. (Quartz provides only SimpleThreadPool that run jobs on unmanaged threads). Tell quartz to use this thread pool by `org.quartz.threadPool.class` property
2. Tell quartz to use `WorkManagerThreadExecutor` (or implement custom one) by `org.quartz.threadExecutor.class` property
3. A bit patience with cumbersome legacy web containers :)

Here is [**github demo**](https://github.com/pufface/quartz-minimal) of using Quartz with Websphere (and also Tomcat).

Hope it helps someone..

Answer (score 1):

You can check the below JIRA link raised on quartz regarding this.

http://jira.opensymphony.com/browse/QUARTZ-708

This has the required WebSphereThreadPool implementation which can be used with the changes in quartz.properties as mentioned to meet your requirements. Hope this helps.

Regards,
Siva

Answer (score 1):

You will have to use websphere's managed thread pools.  You can do this via spring and commonj.  CommonJ can has a task executor that will create managed threads.  You can even use a reference to a jndi managed thread resource.  You can then inject the commonj task executor into the Spring based Quartz SchedulerFactoryBean.

Please see http://open.bekk.no/boss/spring-scheduling-in-websphere/ and scroll to "Quartz with CommonJ" section for more details.

Answer (score 1):

The proposal from PaoloC for WAS85 ans Quartz 1.8.6 also works on WAS80 (and Quartz 1.8.6) and does not need Spring. (In my setup Spring 2.5.5 is present, but not in use in that context.)

That way I was able to override SimpleJobFactory by my own variant, using an InjectionHelper to apply CDI on every newly created job. Injection works for both @EJB (with JNDI lookup of the annotated EJB remote business interface) and @Inject (with JNDI lookup of the CDI BeanManager using a new InitialContext first, and then using this newly fetched BM to lookup the CDI bean itself).

Thank you PaoloC for that answer! (I hope this text will appear as an "answer to PaoloC" and not as an answer to the main topic. Found no way to differentiate between these.)