# Zombie threads eating my brainz (J2EE, Tomcat, Hibernate, Quartz)

Tags: java, tomcat, jakarta-ee, multithreading, quartz-scheduler

It *is* Hallowe'en after all.

Here's the problem: I'm maintaining some old-ish J2EE code, using Quartz, in which I'm running out of threads.  `jconsole` tells me that there are just short of 60K threads when it goes pear-shaped, of which about 100 (!!) are actually running.  Intuition and some googling (see also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/175880/unmanaged-threads-spring-quartz-websphere-hibernate)) suggest that what's happening is something (I'm betting Quartz) is creating unmanaged threads that never get cleaned up.

Several subquestions:

1. It there a tool that I can use easily to trace thread creation, so I can be certain the issue is really Quartz?
2. Most everything I've found about similar problems references Weblogic; is this a false lead for Tomcat?
3. Does anyone have a known solution?

It's been years since I did J2EE, so I wouldn't be too surprised if this is something that can be solved simply.

***Update***:  It's clearly increasing threads without bound, see this plot from jconsole.

[image: They're dead, Jim]

Comment: Do you notice any pattern in the names of the threads? I would suspet the problem is the code that uses Quartz, not Quartz itself

Comment: +1 for the title, tells me everything I needed to know.  Did you try the shotgun?

Comment: Matt, I'm really out of date with JEE debugging tools (just asked a separate question for recommendations: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1650881/state-of-the-art-in-j2ee-debugging-and-monitoring-tools/1650922#1650922) so I haven't yet.  But there is a known Quartz bug causing it to spawn unmanaged threads.

Comment: Anthony, I'd like to try the shotgun on both application and client.  Upon legal advice, I refrained.

Comment: Oh man, I know some women who'd kill for thread counts that high :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Try to increase the logging level of `org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool` to debug to get more information.
- If that does not work, try a logging listener. Quartz has a JobListener interface, which is specified in its [tutorial](http://www.opensymphony.com/quartz/wikidocs/TutorialLesson7.html). A listener can help you trace job execution. Maybe jobs just don't finish and get deadlocked.
- Configure `org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount` to stop running out of threads.

**update:**

- Also, you might want to take a thread dump and see the thread stats. [visual vm](http://visualvm.dev.java.net) has a plugin called TDA, or you can use [Thread dump analyzer](https://tda.dev.java.net/) directly.
- Just in case, check the quartz version to see if there is no known bug.

Comment: Marcelo, the jconsole plot shows the threads are clearly growing unboundedly.  Hmm, I should include that picture.

Answer (score 0):

Have you had a look with jvisualvm - it gives some more information.

Also, get stack traces to see what the threads are actually waiting on.  You might have an aha-feeling right there.