# state of the art in Java EE debugging and monitoring tools

Tags: debugging, tomcat, jakarta-ee

I'm digging into Java EE for the first time in years.  I'm looking for recommendations on Java EE debugging and monitoring tools.  I'd *like* to find a tool that lets me dynamically explore the threads space etc.

I'm primarily working with Tomcat.  ***update***: and Java 5.  (Rats.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are unable to use **VisualVM** (not sure how it plays with Java5 instances), take a look at [**Lambda Probe**](http://www.lambdaprobe.org/d/overview.shtml).

[**Lambda Probe**](http://www.lambdaprobe.org/d/overview.shtml) may not have all of the features you want (e.g. threads), but does have quite a few monitoring features and **works with Java 4 and 5**.

> - New! Comprehensive JVM memory usage monitor.
> - JBoss compatibility
> - Display of deployed applications, their status, session    count,
>     session object count, context
>     object count, datasource usage etc.
> - Start, stop, restart, deploy and updeploy of applications
> - Ability to view deployed JSP files
> - Ability to compile all or selected JSP files at any time.
> - Ability to pre-compile JSP files on application deployment.
> - New! Ability to view auto-generated JSP servlets
> - Display of list of sessions for a particular application
> - Display of session attributes and their values for a particular
>     application. Ability to remove
>     session attributes.
> - Ability to view application context attributes and their values.
> - Ability to expire selected sessions
> - Graphical display of datasource details including maximum number of
>     connections, number of busy
>     connections and configuration details
> - New! Ability to group datasource properties by URL to help
>     visualizing impact on the databases
> - Ability to reset data sources in case of applications leaking
>     connection
> - Display of system information including System.properties, memory
>     usage bar and OS details
> - Display of JK connector status including the list of requests
>     pending execution
> - Real-time connector usage charts and statistics.
> - Real-time cluster monitoring and clulster traffic charts
> - New! Real time OS memory usage, swap usage and CPU utilisation
>     monitoring
> - Ability to show information about log files and download selected
>     files
> - Ability to tail log files in real time from a browser.
> - Ability to interrupt execution of "hang" requests without server
>     restart
> - New! Ability to restart Tomcat/JVM via Java Serview Wrapper.
> - Availability "Quick check"
> - Support for DBCP, C3P0 and Oracle datasources
> - Support for Tomcat 5.0.x and 5.5.x
> - Support for Java 1.4 and Java 1.5

Comment: Thanks.  I hadn't realized java5 was EOL this week; I guess i should consider converting once Im track this down.

Answer (score 0):

The state-of-the-art is probably [`VisualVM`](https://visualvm.dev.java.net/).