# quartz scheduler cannot acquire trigger

Tags: spring, jdbc, db2, websphere, quartz-scheduler

I am working with a client and getting issues where jobs are not triggered from time to time.

Here is an example of an error, this is happening frequently and also causing jobs not to be triggered.

```
Mon, 15 May 2017 04:54:03-04:00 2017-05-15T08:54:03.0000405Z [xyz_QuartzSchedulerThread] ERROR c.v.i.c.s.s.s.QuartzMonitorImpl - Failure encountered by the Quartz Scheduler, An error occurred while scanning for the next triggers to fire.
org.quartz.JobPersistenceException: Couldn't acquire next trigger: The current transaction has been rolled back because of a deadlock or timeout.  Reason code "2".. SQLCODE=-911, SQLSTATE=40001, DRIVER=3.69.49
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.acquireNextTrigger(JobStoreSupport.java:2848) ~[quartz-2.2.1.jar:na]
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport$40.execute(JobStoreSupport.java:2759) ~[quartz-2.2.1.jar:na]
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport$40.execute(JobStoreSupport.java:2757) ~[quartz-2.2.1.jar:na]
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.executeInNonManagedTXLock(JobStoreSupport.java:3787) ~[quartz-2.2.1.jar:na]
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.acquireNextTriggers(JobStoreSupport.java:2756) ~[quartz-2.2.1.jar:na]
    at org.quartz.core.QuartzSchedulerThread.run(QuartzSchedulerThread.java:272) ~[quartz-2.2.1.jar:na]
Caused by: com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlTransactionRollbackException: The current transaction has been rolled back because of a deadlock or timeout.  Reason code "2".. SQLCODE=-911, SQLSTATE=40001, DRIVER=3.69.49
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.gd.a(Unknown Source) ~[db2jcc.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.gd.a(Unknown Source) ~[db2jcc.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.gd.a(Unknown Source) ~[db2jcc.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.yo.c(Unknown Source) ~[db2jcc.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.bb.t(Unknown Source) ~[db2jcc.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.bb.l(Unknown Source) ~[db2jcc.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.bb.a(Unknown Source) ~[db2jcc.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.p.a(Unknown Source) ~[db2jcc.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.wb.b(Unknown Source) ~[db2jcc.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.zo.qc(Unknown Source) ~[db2jcc.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.zo.b(Unknown Source) ~[db2jcc.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.zo.ic(Unknown Source) ~[db2jcc.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.zo.executeUpdate(Unknown Source) ~[db2jcc.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJdbcPreparedStatement.pmiExecuteUpdate(WSJdbcPreparedStatement.java:1187) ~[com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJdbcPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(WSJdbcPreparedStatement.java:804) ~[com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:na]
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.StdJDBCDelegate.updateTriggerStateFromOtherState(StdJDBCDelegate.java:1439) ~[quartz-2.2.1.jar:na]
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.acquireNextTrigger(JobStoreSupport.java:2827) ~[quartz-2.2.1.jar:na]
    ... 5 common frames omitted
Mon, 15 May 2017 04:54:03-04:00 2017-05-15T08:54:03.0000408Z [settlementScheduler_QuartzSchedulerThread] ERROR org.quartz.core.ErrorLogger - An error occurred while scanning for the next triggers to fire.
org.quartz.JobPersistenceException: Couldn't acquire next trigger: The current transaction has been rolled back because of a deadlock or timeout.  Reason code "2".. SQLCODE=-911, SQLSTATE=40001, DRIVER=3.69.49
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.acquireNextTrigger(JobStoreSupport.java:2848) ~[quartz-2.2.1.jar:na]
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport$40.execute(JobStoreSupport.java:2759) ~[quartz-2.2.1.jar:na]
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport$40.execute(JobStoreSupport.java:2757) ~[quartz-2.2.1.jar:na]
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.executeInNonManagedTXLock(JobStoreSupport.java:3787) ~[quartz-2.2.1.jar:na]
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.acquireNextTriggers(JobStoreSupport.java:2756) ~[quartz-2.2.1.jar:na]
    at org.quartz.core.QuartzSchedulerThread.run(QuartzSchedulerThread.java:272) ~[quartz-2.2.1.jar:na]
Caused by: com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlTransactionRollbackException: The current transaction has been rolled back because of a deadlock or timeout.  Reason code "2".. SQLCODE=-911, SQLSTATE=40001, DRIVER=3.69.49
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.gd.a(Unknown Source) ~[db2jcc.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.gd.a(Unknown Source) ~[db2jcc.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.gd.a(Unknown Source) ~[db2jcc.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.yo.c(Unknown Source) ~[db2jcc.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.bb.t(Unknown Source) ~[db2jcc.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.bb.l(Unknown Source) ~[db2jcc.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.bb.a(Unknown Source) ~[db2jcc.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.p.a(Unknown Source) ~[db2jcc.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.wb.b(Unknown Source) ~[db2jcc.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.zo.qc(Unknown Source) ~[db2jcc.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.zo.b(Unknown Source) ~[db2jcc.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.zo.ic(Unknown Source) ~[db2jcc.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.zo.executeUpdate(Unknown Source) ~[db2jcc.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJdbcPreparedStatement.pmiExecuteUpdate(WSJdbcPreparedStatement.java:1187) ~[com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJdbcPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(WSJdbcPreparedStatement.java:804) ~[com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:na]
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.StdJDBCDelegate.updateTriggerStateFromOtherState(StdJDBCDelegate.java:1439) ~[quartz-2.2.1.jar:na]
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.acquireNextTrigger(JobStoreSupport.java:2827) ~[quartz-2.2.1.jar:na]
    ... 5 common frames omitted
```

Details of environment

- Db2
- Websphere(4 instances with jndi datasource)
- p series with ibm jdk 8
- Spring version 4
- Quartz version 2.2.1 (clustered)
- Properties

  datasource.db2.driverClassname=com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver
  org.quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateClass=org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.StdJDBCDelegate
  org.quartz.threadPool.class=org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool
  org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount=5
  org.quartz.jobStore.class=org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreCMT
  org.quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateClass=org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.StdJDBCDelegate
  org.quartz.jobStore.tablePrefix=T_QRTZ_
  org.quartz.scheduler.skipUpdateCheck=true
  org.quartz.jobStore.isClustered=true
  org.quartz.jobStore.clusterCheckinInterval=20000
  org.quartz.scheduler.instanceId=AUTO

Would appreciate if someone has already faced the issue and can shed some light on this

Comment: Have you checked this in your WebSphere? http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21440972

Comment: You seem to be suffering deadlock problems in your DB2 database. Maybe this can help you: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.trb.doc/doc/t0055074.html

Comment: May be setting **org.quartz.jobStore.txIsolationLevelSerializable=true** might help. It's [documented](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.2.x/configuration/ConfigJobStoreTX.html) as _This can be helpful to prevent lock timeouts with some databases under high load, and “long-lasting” transactions_

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem. Quartz complained about **deadlock or timeout** - similar to your stacktrace. In my case, exception message was bit misleading, because **it actually meant no connection** to database at all.

- Make sure that you meet required criteria for using `JobStoreCMT` according to [quartz documentaiton](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.2.x/configuration/ConfigJobStoreCMT.html):

  > ...A JTA **transaction must be in progress** before attempt to schedule (or unschedule) jobs/triggers. This allows the “work” of scheduling to be part of the applications “larger” transaction...
- Be aware - your scheduled jobs run in **unmanaged threads** (outside Websphere) as long as using `SimpleThreadPool`. Unmanaged thread **does not have access to server context** (including data sources, jndi , etc.)
- Consider to use `JobStoreTX` and run jobs inside managed threads provided by `WorkManagers`, see [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/175880/unmanaged-threads-spring-quartz-websphere-hibernate/43793069#43793069) and [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43793069/6451286) with [github-example](https://github.com/pufface/quartz-minimal).